# Understanding empty set, set with empty set and set with set of empty set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble understanding the difference between these sets.

$\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},...$

I think they're supposed to be different to eachother, but I read that [the empty set is a subset of every set including itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528630/is-the-null-set-a-subset-of-every-set).

So every set in $\emptyset$ is in $\{\emptyset\}$ and every set in $\{\emptyset\}$ is in $\emptyset$. So they're subsets of each other and therefore the same set.

So $\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},...$ are all the same. Is this right?

Comment: No. $\emptyset$ has no element, while $\{\emptyset\}$ has one element.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to think of the empty set as $\{\}$, so $\{\} \in \{\{\}\}$.

Comment: "So every set in ∅ is in {∅} and every set in {∅} is in ∅." NO; there are **no** sets in $\emptyset$ while there is exactly **one** set in $\{ \emptyset \}$. Thus, the two are **not** the same.

Answer (score 4):

It might also help to think of the sets as being boxes, which might contain any number of objects (including infinite).  For instance, the set $S = \{\text{apple}, \text{ball}, \text{corkscrew}\}$ might be represented by an actual box containing an apple, a ball, and a corkscrew.

In this analogy, the empty set $A = \varnothing$ is just an empty box.  Being the empty set, it is a subset of any other set.  That would mean that every item in the empty box is also in every other box.  That is manifestly true: There are no items in the empty box that aren't also in every other box.

Note that the empty set is not an *element* of every other set.  For example, the box representing the set $S$ contains three ordinary objects, but does not contain an empty box.

However, something that *would* contain an empty box would be $B = \{\varnothing\}$, which would be represented by a box that contains only an empty box (which would represent $A$).  And $C = \{\{\varnothing\}\}$ would be—you guessed it—a box, which contains only a box, which in turn contains only an empty box.

Observe that these various boxes are evidently not the same: Something that contains only an empty box is not the same thing as an empty box.

(Please don't ask me about $\{\text{box}\}$.)

Answer (score 0):

It is true that every element of the empty set $\varnothing$ is an element of $\{\varnothing\}$ (since the empty set $\varnothing $ has no elements) but it is not true that every element of $\{\varnothing\}$ is an element of $\varnothing$. Indeed, $\varnothing\in \{\varnothing\}$ but $\varnothing\notin \varnothing$. So $\varnothing \subset \{\varnothing\}$ but $\{\varnothing\}$ is not a subset of $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

$\phi$ simply means the set is empty, i.e has no elements. Eg. A= $\phi$ implies A is an empty set.

On the other hand, {$\phi$} means a set S= {$\phi$} has the element $\phi$ $\Rightarrow$ $\phi \in$ {$\phi$}

Similarly, $\phi \in$ {$\phi$} $\in$ {{$\phi$}}