# Is $\emptyset \subseteq P(A)$ or $\{\emptyset\}\subseteq P(A)$, where $A$ is a set and $P(A)$ is the power set of $A$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I think my professor made an error on his answer key and I'm trying to confirm it before I bring it to his attention. He asserts only 1.) is false. **I believe both 1 and 4 are false.** This class is only using naïve set theory.

> $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$
> Select the statement that is false
>
> 1.) $\{2,3\} \subseteq P(A)$
> 2.) $\{2,3\} \in P(A)$
> 3.) $ \emptyset \in P(A)$
> 4.) $\emptyset \subseteq P(A)$

- $P(A)$ is the set of all the subsets of $A$

  - $P(A) = P(A) = \{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}$

1. FALSE

   - $2$ is not an element of $P(A)$
   - $3$ is not an element of $P(A)$
   - ∴ $\{2,3\}$ cannot be a subset of $P(A)$
   - $\{{2,3}\}$ would be a subset of $P(A)$
2. TRUE

   - The element $\{2,3\}$ can be found in the set $P(A)$
3. TRUE

   - The element $\emptyset$ can be found in the set $P(A)$
4. FALSE

   - Both operands of the subset operator requires a set. $\emptyset$ is the empty set were as $\{\emptyset\}$ is an element that is the empty set. Therefore $\emptyset$ is not a subset of $P(A)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "The empty set is a subset of any set" a convention?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953218/is-the-empty-set-is-a-subset-of-any-set-a-convention)

Comment: You might also find this one helpful - or look through the linked questions navigation bar (on the right) on these questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528630/ (There's a lot of good answers on this site already explaining why the empty set is a subset of every set)

Answer (score 5):

#4 is true. The empty set is a subset of every set.

It happens that the empty set us also an *element* of this set.

So both $\varnothing \subseteq \mathscr{P}(A)$ and $\varnothing \in \mathscr{P}(A)$ are true.

Comment: Okay, so the empty set is implicit. Does this mean that 1st element I listed in P(A) can express the following statement: {{}} ⊆ P(A)?

Comment: You’ve made several errors. You have correctly included the empty set, but you have omitted all subsets with 3 or 4 elements, and note that $\{2\}$ and $\{2,2\}$ are the same set containing the single element $2$.

Answer (score 4):

You are wrong: both $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$ are subsets of $\mathcal P(A)$. $\varnothing$ is a subset of any set $X$, because the condition of all its elements being elements of $X$ is vacuously true; $\{\varnothing\}$ is a subset of $\mathcal P(A)$ because $\varnothing\in\mathcal P(A)$, seeing as $\varnothing\subseteq A$.

$\{\varnothing\}$ is a set, specifically the set containing exactly the element $\varnothing$. Its existence is implied by the axiom of pair and the axiom of empty set together.

Answer (score 2):

The empty set is a subset of every set, so it is also true that $\emptyset \subset P(A)$.

Comment: @Sumanta: the power set is always non-empty, so it is appropriate to use the symbol ‘$\subset$‘.